# Update nested json array fields in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

Please share your thought on how to update on below field

```
"UserList": [ 
   { 
      "userAge":33,
      "empID":32,
      "empSal":120000,
      "userDept":{ 
         "deptId":1,
         "deptEmpCount":10,
         "deptNo":2
      }
   },
   { 
      "userAge":33,
      "empID":31,
      "empSal":120000,
      "userDept":{ 
         "deptId":1,
         "deptEmpCount":10,
         "deptNo":2
      }
   }
]
```

want to update `deptEmpCount` and `deptId` based on `empID`.
I also want to remove objects based on `empID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition to Roi Katz answer updating more than one array field and removing from object from array.

To update array element you must use update-for syntax and last example https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html 
Update 2 fields you must use SET clause with each has its own FOR.
Unset you can use same way.

```
UPDATE default AS d
SET u.userDept.deptEmpCount = u.userDept.deptEmpCount+1 FOR u IN d.UserList WHEN u.empID = 31 END,      
    u.userDept.deptId = 2 FOR u IN d.UserList WHEN u.empID = 31 END
UNSET u.userDept.deptNo FOR u IN d.UserList WHEN u.empID = 31 END
WHERE ...;
```

To remove object from the ARRAY you can construct new array and assign it

```
UPDATE default AS d
SET d.UserList = ARRAY u FOR u IN d.UserList WHEN u.empID != 31 END
WHERE ...;
```

If you want to do complex operations on ARRAY by using subquery expression (FROM clause of subquery using expression from the parent) and able to do complete SQL on ARRAY as source of documents.

Example: Removing empID = 31 and sorting array by empID and limiting size of array to 5.

```
UPDATE default AS d
    SET d.UserList = (SELECT u.* 
                      FROM d.UserList AS u 
                      WHERE u.empID != 31 
                      ORDER BY u.empID  
                      LIMIT 5)
    WHERE ...;
```

To Add new object to UserList

```
UPDATE default AS d
SET d.UserList = ARRAY_APPEND(d.UserList, { "userAge": 34, "empID": 33, "empSal": 120000, "userDept": { "deptId": 1, "deptEmpCount": 10, "deptNo": 3 } })
WHERE ...
```

To Add new object to UserList if not there, if there update it.

```
UPDATE default d
SET d.UserList = (CASE WHEN (FIRST u FOR u IN d.UserList WHEN u.empID = 33 END) IS MISSING
                       THEN ARRAY_APPEND(d.UserList,
                           { "userAge": 34, "empID": 33, "empSal": 120000, "userDept": { "deptId": 1, "deptEmpCount": 10, "deptNo": 3 } })
                       ELSE d.UserList END
                  END),
     u.userDept.deptId = 2 FOR u IN d.UserList WHEN u.empID = 33 END
WHERE ....
```

Comment: thanks, suppose we want to add one new object to  UserList like { 
      "userAge":34,
      "empID":35,
      "empSal":130000,
      "userDept":{ 
         "deptId":4,
         "deptEmpCount":10,
         "deptNo":3
      }
   }

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to clarify, CouchDB is not Couchbase :)

```
UPDATE myBucket1 AS d 
SET o.empSal = "120001" FOR o IN d.UserList WHEN o.empID = 32 END
```

Now in order to remove, you just do something similar, just use the unset keyword.
presume you have another field in the array called "dummy".

```
UPDATE myBucket1 AS d
UNSET o.dummy  FOR o IN d.UserList WHEN o.empID = 32 END
```

as far as i'm aware since we are talking on array, you can't currently combine them both.

please note, that you should specify a where clause. Since you have only 1 document it doesn't really matter, but in real life- you should.

please also look at the documentation for further instructions
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html